# Can't access ASP.NET Website Administration Tool on Windows 8.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, website-admin-tool

I developed a site on `ASP.Net 4.0` in `VS2013` and used `ASP.Net Membership Provider`.
I ***want to create roles and assign them to users*** but there is no way to access `ASP.Net Website Administration Tool` from `VS2013` i suppose.

I tried [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1940600.aspx?Where%20is%20website%20administrator%20tools%20in%20vs%202013%20RC) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/08/19/asp-net-web-configuration-tool-missing-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx) solutions but the problem here is windows 8.1.
On step 3, It prompts **"This App can't run on your pc"**

Also there is no ASP.Net Configuration in website menu

What should i do in this case? Is there any other way of Role creation and assignment?

Answer (score 0):

To access the Web Site Administration Tool, on the Website menu, click ASP.Net Configuration.

Please refer more for your information

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy40ytx0(v=vs.100).aspx
```

Comment: There is no ASP.Net Configuration in website menu